No module named 'ezdxf'
I'm writing an add-on in vscode to export some geometries as dxf files. When I try to import ezdxf, i get an ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ezdxf'.
I have ezdxf installed on my computer and can run it just fine in vscode.
I'm using the blender developement add-on for vscode, and using the fake-bpy-module by nutti.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT: Following Jakemoyo's advice, I copied the ezdxf file into the modules folder In the blender scripting directories.

You'll need to find the folder containing ezdxf in your regular Python site-packages folder and then copy that into your modules folder.

Thank you, this has helped. I'm still new to scripting in general.
